# jsp tag inside javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

i have objects of two classes which returning from servlet on jsp page.

```
public class Port {

private String portName;
private boolean acceptability;

//getters and setters ... }
```

this is my Components class which have Ports objects

```
public class Component {



private int id;

private String name,icon;

private List<Port> inputPorts;

private List<Port> outputPorts;

//getters and setters ...


}
```

this is my java script code

```js
<script>
    makeComponent("Menu", "image.png", "green",
                  [makePort("input", true)],
                  [makePort("output", false)]);
</script>
```

and i want to put object value inside script tag

i tried this but it is not working

```
 <script>
<c:forEach items="${components}" var="component">                           

    makeComponent("${component.name}", "image.png", "green",
          [<c:forEach items="$components.inputPorts" var="inputPort">
                makePort("$inputPort.portName", ${inputPort.acceptability}),

          </c:forEach>],
          [makePort("OUT", false)]
);
</c:forEach>  </script>
```

is this logic correct? can i use jstl tags in javascript  block?

Comment: *How* is it not working? What does the resulting JavaScript look like?

Comment: You have a typo  in the last piece of code when calling the function, at leat the parenthesis are wrong placed.

Comment: is this logic correct? can i use jstl tag in '<script> </script>'

Comment: save your page as jsp and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exception was ',' after makePort function

i added:  `<c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>` this code and it works

```
<c:forEach items="${components}" var="component">                           

makeComponent("${component.name}","images/55x55.png","green",
        [
             <c:forEach items ="${component.inputPorts}" var="port" varStatus="loop">

                makePort("${port.portName}", ${port.acceptability})
                <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>

             </c:forEach>
        ],
        [
            <c:forEach items ="${component.outputPorts}" var="port">
            makePort("${port.portName}", ${port.acceptability})
            <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>

         </c:forEach>
        ]);
```